# how can we show UIView by using cocos2d with animation?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

how can i show a UIView using cocos2d with animation, i have used code like:

[[[Director sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:myView];

but this without any animation, so how can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to detail your question a bit better.  What exactly is not working for animation?  Do you see sprites on screen but they are not animating?  Can you provide some sample code of how you are creating animations?